# Variational Autencoders and the inequality $\mathbb{E}_{z∼q(z|x)}log (p_{model}(x | z)) − D_{KL}(q(z | x)||p_{model}(z)) ≤ log (p_{model}(x))$

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I am reading section $20.10.3$ of the book Deep Learning on Variational Autoencoders, where the authors write:

> To generate a sample from the model, the VAE ﬁrst draws a sample $z$
> from the code distribution $p_{model}(z)$. The sample is then run
> through a differentiable generator network $g(z)$. Finally, $x$ is
> sampled from a distribution $p_{model}(x;g(z)) =p_{model}(x | z)$.
> During training, however, the approximate inference network (or
> encoder) $q(z | x)$ is used to obtain $z$, and $p_{model}(x | z)$ is
> then viewed as a decoder network.The key insight behind variational
> autoencoders is that they can be trained by maximizing the variational
> lower bound $L(q)$ associated with data point $x:$
>
> $$L(q) = \mathbb{E}_{z∼q(z|x)}log (p_{model}(z, x)) + H(q(z | x))$$
> $$= \mathbb{E}_{z∼q(z|x)}log (p_{model}(x | z)) − D_{KL}(q(z |
> > x)||p_{model}(z))$$ $$≤ log (p_{model}(x))$$

I'm not sure about the last inequality. I know that the $KL$ divergence is always positive, but I'm not sure why the expectation is not present. By definition:
$\mathbb{E}_{z∼q(z|x)}log (p_{model}(x | z)) = \sum_{z \in Z} q(z|x) log (p_{model}(x | z))$, but how does this relate to $log (p_{model}(x))$?

Comment: Machine learning maths always strike me as sloppy and lacking details. Total disservice in my opinion

Comment: @Snoop I would unfortunately have to agree. What I often do is just skip over passages that are badly written because it's a waste of time. In this case I'd like to figure out how this inequality is arrived at so I can understand the ELBO lower bound better.

Comment: The context might be this one: let $Z,X$ be random variables, $B$ a Borel set, then by Jensen's inequality
$$E[\ln(P(X\in B|Z))|X]\leq \ln(E[P(X\in B|Z)|X])$$
However, you would have to piece together the notation and the rest of the discourse to come to the conclusion (if at all).